# When excatly onPageStarted is being called?

Tags: android

Im working on a project that measures the length of web page's loading time.
I do this by having an invisible WebView in the activity, and then measuring time between different WebClient's methods, however Im having a problem with measuring something called "setup time", which is basically a time difference between requesting a website and the moment when the web site started to be downloaded/rendered.

Im trying to achieve this by notifying the time bofore I call 
webview.loadUrl() and 
webclient.onPageStarted() event. It works fine except when I try to measure multiple sites one after another.
The first site will have setup time of around 0.2s to 1s, the second from 0.05 to 0.2s and the last one is always in the range og 0.001-0.002s, which simply can not be real.

This happens every time, not just once - the setup time keeps decreasing to a around 0.002s.

Do you have any tips why is this happening? Why is onPageStarted being called so fast?
Thank you

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Log.i("MEASUREMENT", "loadUrl");
wv.loadUrl( currentURL, noCacheHeaders );
```

and then

```
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    Log.i("MEASUREMENT", "onPageStarted");
    setupTime = (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)/1000.0;
}
```

Comment: I even tried to recreate WebView every time I load new URL, but it didnt change anything.